# Loop counter missing odd numbers with fread in c

Tags: c, loops

hi guys i have this function to tell me how many records are in a data file.
however whenever i run it it only reads the even records

ex: if i have 0 records it outputs 0

with 1 record it outputs 0

with 2 records it ouputs 1

with 3 it outputs 1

with 4 it outputs 2

(btw its for a customer and products database project
customer is a struct and filep is the pointer to the file customerfile which is defines above this code)
im running on eclipse and can only use the gnu89/90 dialect if that makes a diff

```
   int CusFileNumber(void)
{
    customer tempcus;
    filep = fopen(customersFile, "r");
    fseek (filep,0,SEEK_SET);
    int counter =0;

    while(!feof(filep))
    {
        fread(&tempcus,sizeof(customer),1,filep);
        printf ("%d",counter);
        counter ++;
    }
    fclose(filep);
    return (counter-1);
}
```

---

so i updated the code to get rid of the feof

it looks like this

```
int CusFileNumber(void)
{
    customer tempcus;
    filep = fopen(customersFile, "r");
    fseek (filep,0,SEEK_SET);
    int counter =0;

    while(fread(&tempcus, sizeof(customer), 1, filep) == 1)
    {
        printf ("%d",counter);
        counter ++;
    }
    fclose(filep);
    return (counter);
}
```

but im still getting the same problem this time it isnt counting the even numbers

meaning that on every odd number counter increments by 1 but stayed the same when i have an even number of records in the file
(its a .dat file btw)

Comment: Loosely speaking, `feof()` is always wrong.

Comment: so ive heard, i changed it with what carl told me `while (fread(&tempcus, sizeof(customer), 1, filep) != 1)` but i get an infinite loop when i have 1 record in the file

Comment: and any other number of records returns a -1 but thats cause i had the counter -1 which i amended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can't use [`feof(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/feof.3.html) like that.  It only tells you if the stream has *already* ended, not that it's about to.  You need to put the [`fread`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/fread.3.html) call into your loop condition and check its return value:

   ```
   while (fread(&tempcus, sizeof(customer), 1, filep) == 1)
   ```

   Get rid of the `feof` call entirely.
2. Are you sure `sizeof(customer)` matches what's really in the file?
3. Why are you printing `counter` before you increment it?
4. Why are you returning `counter - 1` instead of `counter`?

Comment: what do you mean by put `fread` in the loop? its already being done several times.
as in put it as a parameter for the while? and what do i check it with?

Comment: I mean put it in the loop condition.  I have an example right there in my answer.

Comment: its return value is incrementing as it should, except odd numbered records, then it just ignores them

Comment: i put it in the loop condition and it returned a -1 with when i have one record in the file

Comment: Sounds like the answer to my question #2 is "no", then.

Comment: still with fread in the loop condition when i had 2 records it returned 0

with 3 records it also returned 0

then when i had 4 records in the file it returned a 1

Comment: Did you check to see if `sizeof(customer)` is what you expect?

Comment: btw when i did fread....... != 1 it never even entered the loop so i set it to == 1

Comment: And you can check the size by printing it.

Comment: well the size is 64, do i count the number of chars in a record in the file ?

Comment: nope, there are 38 chars and the size of read 68, any idea why?

Comment: Structure padding probably.  Show us the definition of your structure.

Comment: `typedef struct customer

 {

  char name[10];

  char Sname[10];

  char Addr1 [20];

  char Addr2 [20];

  int Id;

 }customer;`

Comment: Well, there you go- that structure is obviously longer than 38 bytes.  Just the arrays add up to 60.

Comment: so like, what do i do about it?

Comment: That depends entirely on your specific problem.  I don't think we can answer that for you here.